# Get php results with jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't know why I am having a hard time with this, but it's about time I came up for air and asked the question.

What is the best way to call a php file with jquery ajax, have it process some inputs via $_GET, return those results and again use ajax to replace the content of a div?

So far, I can call the php file, and in the success of the jquery ajax call I get an alert of the text.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "xxx/xxx.php", 
        type: "GET",
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            alert("HTLM = " + html);
            $('#product-list').html(html);
            }
 });
```

I set the php function to echo the result, the alert spits out the html from the php file.  But I get a side effect. I get the code that the php generated echoed at the top of the page.  So php is doing it's job (by echoing the content).  Next jquery is doing it's job by replacing the div's content with the values from the php file.

How do I stop the php file from echoing the stuff at the top of the page?

Sample code being echoed from php and alerted in the success of jquery ajax

HTML =

```
<div class="quarter">
  <div class="thumb">
    <a href="productinfo.php?prod-code=Y-32Z&cat=bw&sub=">
      <img src="products/thumbs/no_thumb.gif" alt="No Image" border="0" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="labels"><span class="new-label">New</span></div>
  <p><span class="prod-name">32OZ YARD</span></p>
  <p><span class="prod-code">Y-32Z</span></p>
</div>
```

Thanks!!!

-Kris

Comment: could you provide a sample of the markup that's being returned?

Comment: I've added some markup that is being alerted in the success of the jquery ajax.

Comment: Whatever you echo out in the php file will be pumped out by Jquery.  If you dont want it to return in Jquery you cant echo it out on the php page.

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell -Is that the exact markup, or just a piece of it?  If that's all of it, what unwanted content is rendering?

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell - question isn't totally clear.  Are you saying that the returned HTML is showing up inside your #products-list, but also somewhere else (at the top of the page)?

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell - This is a PHP question, not a jQuery one...you're rendering the content then the whole document again, possibly consider using a different page, or a `die` command?

Comment: @timdev, yes.  Take at look at the link I provided in an earlier comment.

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell are you including your php file that you use for your ajax call at the top of the page?  If so you dont need to.  That would cause the data to dump at the top

Comment: @luke Well indeed I am.  If you could post that as a answer, I will comment on that to ask a secondary question.

Comment: I think Luke is probably correct here. I disabled javascript and the content was still there when the page loaded, which can only mean that it's been output without any involvement from jQuery.

Comment: Luke is on the right track.  Prove it to yourself by turning javascript off in your browser - you still get two separate instances of the product list in your markup.  So your PHP code is outputting this stuff in the main page, when it probably shouldn't be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you including your php file that you use for your ajax call at the top of the page? If so you dont need to. That would cause the data to dump at the top.

Ask your question :)

EDIT TO ANSWER QUESTION

```
<div id="product-list">
<?php include 'products.php' ?>
</div>
```

Your ajax function will now overwrite the php content when it runs and outputs to #product-list

Comment: If I use jquery ajax to call the php file and get the content, once the jquery is complete, if I view the source, the content isn't in the source view.  It's there on the page, but not when you view the source.  When I run a spider simulator on it, it doesn't show the content. Is this how jquery ajax works or is there another way to do it?

Comment: No jquery/javascript modifys the page once it is live, spiders do not have javascript enabled so cannot pick up the content.  Why do you need jquery to include the content, can you not just use php?  If anyone were to view your site without javascript enabled (if you were not including the php file) they would not be able to view your products

Comment: How do I include the file so that I can run the initial content load, but then not include it when I need to echo for the jquery+ajax?  I didn't want to do a separate file.

Comment: I have modified my answer, dont include the php file at the top but where you want the contents outputted, i.e div product-list.

Comment: I think I have design issues.  ROFL.  Luke.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to avoid showing the header and body tags, just the contents, you need to detect when the request is `AJAX` at `PHP` side.

Some pseudo-code is:

```
IF (!IS_AJAX)
    HTML
    HEADER
    BODY
ENDIF

CONTENTS

IF (!IS_AJAX)
    /BODY
    /HTML
ENDIF
```

Search for [HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http_x_requested_with) here at stackoverflow

Comment: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is not always available in the $_SERVER array

Comment: I didn't know that, but I'd add a variable to retrieve AJAx content. So, the search for the given header would be closely related

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't exactly clear, but it sounds like you only want to use PART of the response data. If that's the case, then there's 2 ways to go about it:

First, you can check on the PHP side if it's being requested via AJAX. This is the solution I'd use, since it prevents useless data being transferred to the client:

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
...
if(!IS_AJAX) {
    // anything here will NOT be sent in response to ajax requests
}
```

Alternatively, you can mark the part of the response data you wish to use with an ID, then search the returned data for that id:

```
<h1>Don't care about this</h1>
<div id="use_this">This is the useful data.</div>
```

Then for your ajax response callback:

```
success = function(data) {
    data = $(data).find('#use_this');
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: No I want all of the response data.  I am getting the response echoed at the top of the page, as well as the content being loaded into a div with jquery.